# What is this title in the watch command? android-

Tags: command-line, mojave

Running the `watch` command I see this title:

`Every 2.0s: ls                     android-94348784d7dfd533: Mon Feb  4 08:59:54 2019`

The `android` portion is confusing me.  I don't understand what it is referencing. I have no processes, users or devices named `android`

Using watch version  3.3.15

Comment: what argument do you give to your `watch` command?

Comment: doesn't matter - but I realize that this is installed via `homebrew.`  The value is the `hostname` https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/watch.c#L391 but why this particular hostname?  something to do with `procfs` I reckon.

Comment: and sure enough my hostname is `android-94348784d7dfd533` - now to figure why it is using that and not the machine name.

Answer (score 1):

That value is the machine's hostname. The network was assigning this hostname to the machine.